# ASP.NET IIS7 Dynamic 404 Page

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, http-status-code-404

I'm looking for a solution for a dynamic 404 page.

I have a `Page404.aspx` page that requests a WebsiteID parameter in the querystring when it loads.

Let's say each Website has a different 404 page html stored in DB, and in each page load it will show the correct html by the WebsiteID in the QueryString.

Now the tricky thing- How do I redirect the client to the correct 404page, with the CURRENT WebsiteID ?

Hope I was clear enough. Thanks in advance,

Gal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a Global.asax, then create one for your website. 
This assumes that your websites are split up by directory.

In the new Global.asax file there should be

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

   Exception exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError ();

if (ex.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
{
   HttpException httpEx = (HttpException)ex;
   if(httpEx.GetHttpCode() == 404) 
   {

     int websiteID = FindWebsiteID(ctx.Request.Url.ToString());

     string errorPage = string.Format("~/404Page.aspx?={0}",websiteID);

     Response.Redirect(errorPage);
  }
}

public int FindWebsiteID(string url){

//parse the url for the directory and look up the id
//for the website via the directory name

}
```

you may also check out [this article](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages) for additional information.

Comment: But that will send every error 404 to `id=2` - what if my website is id 46?  By hard coding it in the config file you're not letting it be dynamic per website.

Comment: Doesn't every website have it's own config?

Comment: I don't believe there is a server wide 404 redirect option for all pages, I'm pretty sure it must be configured per website.  The only way that I can think of to achieve that would be to modify the machine.config, but it would not be dynamic.

Comment: all websites run under the same application - same web.config